# Angular-2 : Is function call instead in-line boolean condition impact on performance?

Tags: angular

I am working with user authorization and going to disabled button as per condition.

I have already implemented logic, but I wants to know if I use function instead of In-line logic may impact on performance or not?

My logic are as below:

**In line:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!ApplicationManager.Model.CanModifyFramework && ((selectedPage.Scope!='0' && !ApplicationManager.Model.CanModifyConfiguration) || (selectedPage.Scope=='0' && ApplicationManager.Model.CanModifyConfiguration))">Save & Close</button>
```

**Function:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!GetUserAccessability(selectedPage.Scope)">Save & Close</button>

public GetUserAccessability(scope: any): boolean {
    let result: boolean = false;

    if (this.Model.CanModifyFramework) {
        result = true;
    }
    else if (this.Model.CanModifyConfiguration && scope>0)
    {
        result=true
    }       

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular change detection is most efficient when you bind to a field instead of a method.

It's better to use an observable or an event that notifies on changes, instead of polling, and then update the field in the event handler.

Also a good way is to use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and bind to an observable. The `| async` pipe will call `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` every time a new value is emitted.

The worst thing you can do is binding to a method that returns a new array of object instance for each call. This will bring your application to its knees. Your method doesn't do that and therefore isn't that bad.
Binding to a field or `Observable` is IMHO still the better way.

Comment: Wouldn't creating a new variable inside the method like the OP did, push a new value into the stack? Hence decrease performance a little bit?

Comment: Example: `return this.Model.CanModifyFramework || (this.Model.CanModifyConfiguration && scope>0)` isn't this better for the current situation?

Comment: @Gunter : can you please update my code in your answer how I get better performance, I have not deep knowledge as you described in third block (observable, async pipe and other stuff)

Comment: If you have something like `getFoo() { return { bar: 'abc'}; }` then a new object is returned for each call which is the worst case. You would at least need to cache the instance and only return a new one when something actually changed. I don't know what would be a good way to change your code, it depends on where and when `CanModifyFramework` can be updated.

Comment: When we put break point in function then it continuously call the function and come at that point, so it bad or normal?

Comment: No, every time change detection is run, the method will be called. Checking a field is notable more efficient than calling a method, therefore if you just do `return true`, a field is still more efficient than a function (except perhaps the JS VM optimizes that difference away for such simple functions). With `OnPush` you'll reduce the number of calls, because then change detection isn't run as frequently.

Comment: @Gunter : Thanks for your help